# A question on Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, projective-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $T: Gr(n,\mathbb C^{2n}) \rightarrow G(n,\mathbb C^{2n})$ be the involution defined by $W \rightarrow W^{\perp}$ with respect to a symplectic form on $\mathbb C^{2n}$. Is there a direct proof (without referring to the cohomology) of the fact that $T$ induces an involution on the set of young diagrams contained in rectangular diagram of shape $n \times n$ ? And, the involution takes a young diagram to its transpose.

Comment: Which correspondence are you using between Grassmannians and Young diagrams? Can you say something like: Given a Young diagram $\Lambda$, an $n$-subspace $W$ has incidences $\Lambda$ with a reference flag $F$ if and only if $W^\perp$ has incidences $\Lambda^T$ with the flag $F^\perp$...?

Comment: The symplectic form is sort of a red herring. The general statement is that the canonical isomorphism $Gr(k,V) \to Gr(n-k,V^*)$ (which takes a subspace $W \subset V$ to $(V/W)^* \subset V^*$) maps the Schubert variety for $\lambda$ and a flag $\mathcal{F}$ to the Schubert variety for $\lambda^T$ and the flag $\mathcal{F}^*$. This is direct from the definitions.

Comment: @ Levinson. Thanks, looks correct. Could you please write it as an answer explaining the notations and in a more elaborate form ?

Comment: @ Levinson Why does the isomorphism maps a Schubert variety for $\lambda$ to a Schubert variety for $\lambda^T$ ?